# XML Schema: adding element with immutable value

Tags: xml, xsd

I am busy building an XML schema for an industry standard report. This report has different sections, each section has multiple headings, and under each heading are multiple fields. Most of the fields require some user input; however, there are some fields that are immutable and basically serve as documentation.

The goal is to enable a user to build a report from the XML + XSD without having to reference any other documentation. This means that I would need to define certain elements in the XSD that are static.

Basically I have the following:

```
<heading>
  <field1>user input</field1>
  <field2/> (static) **
  <field3>user input</field3>
</heading>
```

** this is my problem field

Questions (edited based on Paul's response):

1. How can I define a required element
2. that has a non-variable predefined value
3. and is this good design practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sequence` element to define an element content model with a fixed sequence of child elements.

You can use the `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` attributes to declare how many instances of any given element are permitted or required in any given situation (including '0' or 'unbounded').

Regarding simpleContent, you can use the `restriction` element to restrict the possible text content of any given element or attribute.  Within `restriction`, you could possibly use `pattern` (with a regex that only passes for the content you want), `enumeration` (with a single option) or `assertion` (asserting that the value must be the content you want).

`annotation` is useful for providing human-readable documentation, but less so for anything aimed at a machine consumption.

### Addendum for new subquestion

It's not completely unreasonable to have compulsory fixed content, but you should consider the use case carefully.

If the information can reasonably be inferred from the mere existence of the document, then is it really worthwhile including it?

If you are merely codifying an existing standard, then you don't really have a choice. If the content must be there, then that fact should be reflected in the schema.

Comment: I am using these elements and attributes in my XSD. My question is how to specifically use a combination of these to define a 1. required element that 2. should always have the same predefined value and 3. whether this is good design practice

Comment: How have I not answered your question?  Given a sequence, a required element is one that has minOccurs=1, If you want it to have a predefined value, then the paragraph that begins "Regarding simpleContent" gives you some options on how to achieve this.

Comment: Having reread your response I understand. My one remaining question is: is this actually a good idea and is this a common usage pattern?